# Are DevOps tools mandatory to survive in Automation Testing field?

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, aws, test-tools, devops

I work as Test Engineer in Selenium, TestNG, Java, Maven, Cucumber and Jenkins. My knowledge about Jenkins is limited in the sense that I can create freestyle
or Maven based jobs and can trigger those as required and can configure Jenkins comfortably.

Now, I see many of my colleagues learning  Jenkins pipelines or tools like AWS cloud, Docker,  Kubernetes, Google cloud and so on.

Is it mandatory for an automation engineer to learn these kind of tools to sustain in the industry? I see a lot of automation engineers trying to move more into a DevOps engineer sort of profile. How can we justify that trend in the Software Testing field?

Comment: When someone interviews you and your colleagues , if colleagues knows more technologies (T knowledge ) and you only have expertise in selenium.  The choice will be to go for T knowledge , the reason is. That it will surely show case that they are flexible and can learn and adapt to new technologies as they evolve

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you got your base assumption wrong, DevOps is not a silo skill and profession that you either have or not, belong to or don't.

Knowing how to use AWS cloud, Docker, Kubernates or Google cloud is something you will use as a test engineer even before you start developing automation.

Is it mandatory ? obviously not, but you and your career will greatly benefit from it.

How do you justify it? there two way to approach this, first you should know and show that DevOps includes testing as an integral part of the development process and of DevOps itself so if your organization uses DevOps then you are already part of it. Second cloud or container orchestration are great tools to build test automation with, I often use docker containers as a way to get a clean test environment and Jenkins as a test executor.

Comment: Ok thanks for a great  answer.  What do you say about learning Jenkins pipelines? Have you ever used these in your project?

Comment: I don't think I had a project I worked with that did not use Jenkins pipelines as part of testing, the exceptions were projects that used Azure devops pipelines. The basics are quite simple to learn, and copy-paste-modify will get you far.